# brew install npm "npm: command not found"

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, osx-elcapitan

I've installed node using `brew install node` and when I use the `node -v` I get following `v5.0.0`. However when I try to run the `npm` command I get `npm: command not found`.

I've tried to run `brew install npm`, however I just got following response `node-5.0.0 already installed`.

It happened with node also returning command not found, but that I fixed by running `brew link node`, however npm still does not seem to work.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: do you try to run brew doctor? Remove completely nodejs from your system and try to reinstall again

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Try running

```
$ brew postinstall node
```

If you ever ran `sudo npm` / `sudo yarn`, then you might need to change the owner of your global node_modules folder:

```
$ sudo chown -R "$(id -un)" "${NODE_PATH:-/usr/local/lib/node_modules}"
```

Comment: The `--without-npm` option is no longer valid

Comment: This saved the day for me, thank you!

Answer (score 90):

I encountered the same issue. After searching and reading different things online, what worked for me was:

```
$ brew postinstall node
```

However, first please do execute:

```
$ brew doctor
```

and follow the instructions there first, like the comment in your question mentions.

Comment: For me this was due to a linking issue when running `brew install node`.  After having successfully running `brew link node` I also needed to run `brew postinstall node` for it to add `npm` too.

Comment: THANK YOU! you made my day sir!

Comment: After finding dozens of how-tos with hundreds of lines of instructions that go deep into the guts of Homebrew, this worked and should be the correct answer.

Comment: UPDATE: Although this does work, running `brew remove --force yarn && brew remove --force node` then running `brew install node` fixed npm so that I didn't need to call `brew postinstall node` anymore.  Then I called `brew install yarn`.  So I think part of the problem was having multiple versions of yarn and/or node installed.

Comment: `brew doctor` helped me remember I had contributed so my core repo was not in master, then I could reinstall node and it fixed it

Answer (score 49):

Try the following:

`$ brew update`
`$ brew uninstall node`
`$ brew install node`
`$ sudo chown -R YourLocalUserName /usr/local/lib/node_modules/`
`$ brew postinstall node`

Comment: this is a proper working answer for mac users. step 4 is the solution to the issue

Comment: Thanks, it works for me. The only thing is -R username. Actually, I think sudo brew posinstall node might work too if it's a privilege problem.

Comment: Worked for me (and step 4 was my missing link)

Answer (score 3):

the same problem with you, I fixed by:

`/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js i -g npm`

Comment: This worked for me, and other nodejs packages won't be lost, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

running: `echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/node@16/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc` should work, change node@16 to just node or which ever version you just installed.

Comment: Might be obvious, but this works only if you're using ZSH

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by running `brew link node@18`, remember to use `@` if you installed a specific version from the brew, otherwise `brew link node` should work.

If you are not sure what version you install, you can go to the folder `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/` to check what version of node you have installed.

Answer (score 0):

I used cyrillic (non-latin) characters in my hostname/computername on mac. And that was the problem. After i changed this and reinstalled node/npm with Homebrew everything worked like normal. No utf8 in 2017? :/