# how to update npm on macOS

Tags: macos, npm

For reasons unknown to me, I haven't been able to update to the latest version of npm on macOS (it works fine on Windows). ***It displays no error, only 'updated 1 package'.***

Using Node.js 8.11.1

```
node -v
v8.11.1
```

What version of npm do I have?

```
$ npm -v
5.6.0
```

I tried this...

```
$ npm i -g npm
+ npm@5.8.0
updated 1 package in 7.37s
```

And it fails to update.

```
$ npm -v
5.6.0
```

Where is npm?

```
$ which npm
/usr/local/bin/npm
```

So I try `brew`...

```
brew install npm
```

And it fails...

```
$ npm -v
5.6.0
```

***And then I tried this... ***

```
npm install npm@latest -g
+ npm@5.8.0
updated 1 package in 7.618s
```

And it fails...

```
npm -v
5.6.0
```

---

***With `sudo`:***

```
sudo npm i -g npm
+ npm@5.8.0
updated 1 package in 7.794s
```

And it fails...

```
npm -v
5.6.0
```

***This also fails...***

```
sudo npm install npm@latest -g
```

---

I followed the [directions found on this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x), completely removing npm and node from my system and reinstalling them from scratch, and it also fails to update.

---

Screenshot, per request:

[image]

---

Close the terminal, and then re-open the terminal and running:

```
$ npm -v
5.6.0
```

---

`sudo` twice:

```
$ sudo npm i -g npm
+ npm@5.8.0
updated 1 package in 7.478s
$ sudo npm i -g npm
+ npm@5.8.0
updated 1 package in 7.434s
```

Also fails:

```
$ npm -v 
5.6.0
```

---

What did I miss? What's going on here?

Comment: have you tried sudo npm i -g npm ?

Comment: @Squish yes, it was the first thing I tried, but I'll make that clearer.

Comment: Try using sudo in that case. "sudo npm i -g npm"  without the brackets

Comment: @Squish that doesn't work either

Comment: what did the terminal say as an error? please specify

Comment: @Squish terminal displayed no error

Comment: Try this thread on uninstalling and reinstalling the npm, maybe some data got corrupted. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x

Comment: @I followed that thread, completely removed node and npm, and reinstalled, and npm still won't update

Comment: mind showing a screenshot of the terminal?, in this case I dont know what your up against(errors, warning, etc should be helpful). Try doing the "sudo npm install -g npm" twice.Also, try force quiting the terminal and reopening it for a refresh to take effect

Comment: @Squish tried re-opening terminal, and `sudo` twice: they both fail to update npm

Comment: i have the same situation. Either that node installation came preinstalled or we used the installer from NodeJS.org and forgot about it. In any case, when you `ls -l /usr/local/bin/npm` you will see that it links to `../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js`. Not sure whether and how to remove that but the $PATH should be changed to look up the brew version first

Comment: update: this answer finally got me to a PATH that contains the brew-installed node and npm: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44356455/1823536

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Perhaps you have already solved this, but here is what I found when I had exactly this issue. I had 2 versions of npm installed.

I verified this as follows:

```
grep \"version\" ~/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/npm/package.json

  "version": "6.2.0"

grep \"version\" /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/package.json

  "version": "5.6.0",
```

I worked around the issue by updating the path in my bash profile, but would like to know why (how) I ended up with 2 versions. Here is the update:

```
tail -2 ~/.bash_profile

NPM_PACKAGES="${HOME}/.npm-packages"

PATH="$NPM_PACKAGES/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: I think people miss the point of what works about this solution.  Remove the `/usr/local/lib` path and manage npm from .npm-packages, as it should be.

Comment: after trying "this and that" I ended up installing from the nodejs.org package installer doing a custom install (only installing npm)

Comment: Also make sure to have `:$PATH` at the end. In my case it was at the start and shell was using the wrong version.

Answer (score 157):

This works on my mac.

Based on docs https://docs.npmjs.com/troubleshooting/try-the-latest-stable-version-of-npm :

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

There is a note stated on the docs that depends on your installation method, you might addd some `sudo`.

> Upgrading on *nix (OSX, Linux, etc.)
>
> (You may need to prefix these commands with sudo, especially on Linux,
>   or OS X if you installed Node using its default installer.)

Comment: for those curious, -g is the global install flag, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909986/when-should-i-use-npm-with-g-flag-and-why

Comment: `sudo npm install -g npm@latest` works like magic

Comment: You should never install npm with sudo, it's only going to cause more permission headaches later on somewhere. There are many ways to install npm without sudo, brew being one of them, but google for many more.

Comment: Even though I installed node with brew, I could not upgrade it that way. Had to use sudo.

Answer (score 24):

`npm install -g npm@latest`
 works fine!!
and you can also replace the latest for specific versions 
like
`npm install -g npm@5.6.0`

I hope it will help!!!

Answer (score 19):

In my case, only the following has helped:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules
sudo rm -rf ~/.npm
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies node
brew install node
```

**EDIT NOV 21:** These days, I bypass brew entirely and use "n":

https://www.npmjs.com/package/n

And so I can change between versions too.

Comment: This will definitely work if everything else fails. This answer should be on top

Answer (score 15):

In my case, none of the previous answers worked. For me, a working solution was a simple, five-step process.

1. Make sure (the old version of) npm is installed.

`npm -v`

If npm is not installed, then install it on the Mac with [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/).

2. Globally installed the desired version of npm.

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

This command uses the old version of npm (installed by Node), to globally install the latest version of npm at `~/.npm-global/`. Once installed, close and open a new terminal shell.

3. Remove the old version of npm installed by Node

```
rm -r /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/
```

Sometimes this doesn't work, so I had to go into finder to delete the `/npm/` folder.

4. Make sure to set the correct path variable.

```
echo $PATH
```

If `~/.npm-global/bin` does not show up between the colons, then update the path variable. Open up `~/.zshrc` in a text editor and add the following line. If you don't use zsh, open the profile for your corresponding shell (i.e. `~/.bash_profile`)

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.npm-global/bin
```

Save your changes and close the text editor.

5. Close and reopen the terminal shell and run `npm -v` to check that npm is correctly on the latest version.

The reason for updating the path variable is because the npm cli suggests you update npm with `npm install -g npm` which will install npm at a different location than where Node installs npm originally.

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same problem.
You might have already installed the npm version, and now it is time to point the new npm version install. You can do that by following below steps.

1. `sudo nano /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/package.json`
2. change `"version" : "5.6.0"` to `"verison": "5.8.0"`

Comment: Same issue here on MacOS - using `n` to run multiple node versions, but couldn't upgrade `npm` - this setting must manually be changed in the global `node_modules` package.config. Great find!

Comment: This just changes what version is reported on the CLI, not what version is actually being used.

Comment: Thanks, this works for me since I have more than one version of `npm` installed on my MacBook

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I'm using `nvm` to manage different versions of `node`. In order to upgrade npm version, I have to

1 - Install the latest version of npm by navigating to your current
    version of node

```
cd ~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.9.0
npm install npm
```

or you can probably use

```
nvm install-latest-npm
```

2 - Edit `$PATH` to point to your current version of `node`

```
NPM_PACKAGES="${HOME}/.nvm/versions/node/v10.9.0"
PATH="$NPM_PACKAGES/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: The first part of this answer, navigating to the current version that my vm was using and installing there is what worked for me. Like @Mr. 14 said, you go to the node directory, not all the way into the npm directory.

so for me, the location of my npm install for the vm  /usr/local/Cellar/node@8.11.3_1/lib/node_modules/npm  (I'm forced to use an old version due to errors with 10)  and I had to go to /usr/local/Cellar/node@8.11.3_1 and do npm install npm. Then it finally registered the latest version within my vm.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is maybe old, but i'd like to make some kind of update to this issue aswell.

Installed node via brew

`brew install node@20`

Installed newest npm version with

`npm i -g npm@latest`

npm -v shows `10.1.0`

Reason was in .zshrc where i included node@20

`export PATH="/usr/local/opt/node@20/bin:$PATH"`

changed to

`export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/opt/node@20/bin"`

Reason is that there are two versions of npm installed and order of $PATH extension matters if 10.1.0 overwrites 10.2.4 or vice versa

Comment: This should be massively upvoted - keg's post-install instructions misleading. If the OS is picking up the wrong npm, it's probably a path issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yo! I think I've found a simple solution to this , I guess it's mostly a path issue

First Update your npm version to the latest version  **(10.4.0 at the time of writing this)** by doing:

`npm install -g npm@latest`

I downloaded the node package which is **Recommended for Most Users(the version number of the node package is 20.11.1 )**.

But you could try downloading the **Current Latest Features** package from the site ***https://nodejs.org/en***, it should work just the same.

Then go into Finder

Click on:
**Go > Go To Folder**

Paste **/Users/username/.nvm/versions/node** in the search bar.

You will find files of previous Node.js versions , keep the latest version and delete the rest.

Then reopen the terminal

On doing `node --version` you should get the latest version number !

[image]

Answer (score -1):

On my macOS the homebrew-installed npm did not want to upgrade due to pre-existing link file. I ran the install with `--force` flag and now things are okay.

```
$ npm --version
6.14.16
$ npm install -g npm@8
npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, symlink ...
$ npm install -g --force npm@8
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
+ npm@8.19.2
$ npm --version
8.19.2
```

Note also that in my case, no 'sudo' was required, thanks to homebrew. To check if your npm is installed with homebrew, use `brew list`.

```
$ brew list | grep node
node@12
```