# Homebrew install Node.js : Command Not Found

Tags: node.js, macos, terminal, homebrew

I have a Mac running `macOS 10.13.1`. After installing `Homebrew` successfully, I tried to intall `Node.js` with

```
brew install node
```

The installation seems to complete fine in the terminal, however following up with a version check ;

```
node -v
```

results in

```
-bash: node: command not found
```

Any pointers on how to fix this ?, I am trying to avoid to have to install node from binary.

Comment: dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33575082/brew-install-npm-npm-command-not-found

Comment: I'd say avoid using brew or apt-get type tools for node, and just use either N or NVM, https://github.com/creationix/nvm , you can use multiple versions of node and they are super easy to switch too!

Comment: Sounds like it could be a path problem.  What do you get when you type 'which node'

Answer (score 5):

I was having this issue but it was because I was installing an older version of node. For older versions, the path isn't modified automatically to avoid colliding with the potentially installed up to date version. After running the `brew install` command, it should give you instructions on how to add it to your path if thats what you want to do.

Answer (score 5):

try running this command

```
brew link node
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Comment: i used this ```brew link --overwrite node@16``` and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

`brew doctor` should give you some hints.

I just did a fresh installation for my Apple M1, seems just working fine without any additional setup.

```
$ brew install node
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/c-ares/manifests/1.18.1
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/c-ares/blobs/sha256:7b1eacc9efbe8ac32a4a
==> Downloading from https://pkg-containers.githubusercontent.com/ghcr1/blobs/sha256:7b1e
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/libuv/manifests/1.42.0
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/libuv/blobs/sha256:7b0a2b27ac3b806ff9e59
==> Downloading from https://pkg-containers.githubusercontent.com/ghcr1/blobs/sha256:7b0a
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/node/manifests/17.2.0
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/node/blobs/sha256:f3efe9900c885d5bcc3a39
==> Downloading from https://pkg-containers.githubusercontent.com/ghcr1/blobs/sha256:f3ef
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Installing dependencies for node: c-ares and libuv
==> Installing node dependency: c-ares
==> Pouring c-ares--1.18.1.arm64_monterey.bottle.tar.gz
  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/c-ares/1.18.1: 87 files, 665.3KB
==> Installing node dependency: libuv
==> Pouring libuv--1.42.0.arm64_monterey.bottle.tar.gz
  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/libuv/1.42.0: 49 files, 3.5MB
==> Installing node
==> Pouring node--17.2.0.arm64_monterey.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
Bash completion has been installed to:
  /opt/homebrew/etc/bash_completion.d
==> Summary
  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/17.2.0: 2,018 files, 44.4MB
==> Running `brew cleanup node`...
Disable this behaviour by setting HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP.
Hide these hints with HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_HINTS (see `man brew`).
==> Caveats
==> node
Bash completion has been installed to:
  /opt/homebrew/etc/bash_completion.d

$ ls -al /opt/homebrew/bin/node
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ruichen  admin  30 Dec 13 15:56 /opt/homebrew/bin/node -> ../Cellar/node/17.2.0/bin/node

$ node --version
v17.2.0
```